# Ansible : Use pattern for group_vars

Tags: linux, ansible

It is possible to create a group_vars file for a AND group ?

Example,

```
group_vars/DMZ:&WEB
```

It is possible to do something such ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you create a group of groups:

```
[dmz]
dmzhost1
dmzhst2

[web]
webserver1
webserver2

[webdmz:children]
web
dmz
```

Then you create `group_vars/webdmz` so all four hosts have the variable

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups

---

While writing this reply I realised you may mean something else: only apply vars when a host is in both groups at once. In that case I think you need [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html)

```
- name: include vars only when host in BOTH groups
  include_vars:
    file: dmzweb.yaml
  when:
    - "'dmz' in group_names"
    - "'web' in group_names"
```